# Is there some Adobe Air replacement?

Tags: adobe

I use Ubuntu Studio 15.10, 64 bit, and WineHQ 1.9.1.

I've tried to install a Windows software which needs Adobe Air complement, but I can not to install it, not from the original software CD, not from  the Internet.

What's wrong here?

How can I install it?

Is there some "replacement" for Adobe Air, somewhere?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe air is now available for Ubuntu 14.04+

```
wget -O adobe-air.sh http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobe-air.sh
chmod +x adobe-air.sh
sudo ./adobe-air.sh
```

That's it, here is some [more information](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! BTW: I discovered that the reason I couldn't install Air the first time was because we have to install a lot of extra packages when we install Wine. Why there is not instructions about? Or, better, Why not to make an installer which install all those extra and necessary packages? ???

Comment: Extra packages for Wine? I don't use it but as far as I know if you `sudo apt-get install wine`it installs all dependencies but like I said I don't use it so I could be wrong, you could ask another question and see what the community has to say :)

Comment: so, which version of air is that?

Comment: When I finished the first download, automatic the system offered me an upgrade to version 20.... (something). That's what I got.